# How to "Create Group In AD" in an existing group within an exising group in an OU?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, active-directory

In SharePoint 2010 Designer Workflow

- I have created in `OU=OUNAME, CN=EXISTINGGROUPNAME, DC=DOMAIN NAME , DC=.com`
- I can select the OU but **how do I select a group in a group in an OU**?

The path would go to `Domain/OU/Group1/Group2` , How do I do that?  `CN=Group1/Group2?`